# Find key of an array in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 8 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [pid] => 11 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [pid] => 10 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) )
```

as you see this array includes other arrays. Now I want to delete array with `[pid] = 8` , for deleting that I need that array key but I don't know how to find the key of array that have `pid=8` .

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$key = array_search($pid, $cart_e); // $cart_e is above array
```

**For Example:**

For deleting array with `pid = 8` I want the result be like this after deleting:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [pid] => 11 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [pid] => 10 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) )
```

as you see the whole array is deleted (I need this code), in some case I just deleted `pid` that result become like this(I don't want this):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [pid] => 11 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [pid] => 10 [bv] => 0 [bs] => 0 ) )
```

so, How to find the array key of a `pid` with specific `id`?

Comment: `$res = array_filter(function ($x) { return $x['pid'] != 8;}, $array);`

Comment: what is $x? should I replace it with something or just leave it?

Comment: @MSHDeveloper array_filter will iterate each item of your array and $x is the current `element` it is into and checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a new copy of array using array_filter?

```
$array=array(array('pid'=>8,'bv'=>0,'bs'=>0),array('pid'=>11,'bv'=>0,'bs'=>0),array('pid'=>10,'bv'=>0,'bs'=>0));
$newArr = array_filter($array,function($arr){ /* `$arr` gets value of one nested array on each pass */
    return 8 !== $arr['pid'];
});
```

Or, just unset the unwanted nested array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if(8 === $val['pid']){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, please give me a hand for how to use this code. I have two arrays (one parent others are inside). what is $array and $arr?

Comment: Well, it works like a charm, I used your second code for deleting that array. thanks.